# What is a simple way to write GUI apps with clojure?

Tags: clojure, sdk, native, clojurescript, gui-designer

I haven't seen any nice app frameworks for clojure yet. Are there any good sdks with binding for clojure or clojure script?

Comment: When marking this as a duplicate I was assuming you are *not* asking about what the best way to make web-UIs is. If you are asking about making webpages I'll un-dupe it.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt He did mention ClojureScript in his question; I don't know if that's exactly what you mean by "web-UIs", though.

Comment: yes, he could be thinking clojurescript+node.js. I'll wait and see if he comes back and answers.